# How to create a nextjs project with older version?

Tags: next.js

nextjs 13 has been released but when I create a new project I only want to use nextjs version 12, how can I do that?

All the install commands on the nextjs doc are creating a project folder with nextjs 13.
https://nextjs.org/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run this

npx create-next-app && cd myApp && npm i -S next@12

or this

npx create-next-app and then change next version to 12 from package.json manually

Comment: I was looking for create a whole project with structure of a next js 12 project not just change version back to 12 but keep structure at 13